# How can I search on every char with better performance?

Tags: delphi

I have a search field that the user search for every entered chars. So there is no search button. The problem is that the search is slow. My idea is to delay the search after each key entered a bit so if the user enter search string fast it is allowed without searching. Then the search is executed. My code so far.

```
procedure TAgreementModuleForm.SetIsSearching(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  fIsSearching := Value;
  tmrDelayKey.Enabled := Value;
end;

procedure TAgreementModuleForm.tmrDelayKeyTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IsSearching := True;
end;

procedure TAgreementModuleForm.txtSearchAgreementCustomerExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IsSearching := False;
end;

procedure TAgreementModuleForm.txtSearchAgreementCustomerKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
var
  vSearchExpression: string;
begin
  if IsSearching then
  begin
    vSearchExpression := Trim(txtSearchAgreementCustomer.Text);
    IsSearching := False;
    if vSearchExpression <> '' then
      DoSearch(vSearchExpression);
  end
  else
    tmrDelayKey.Enabled := True;
end;
```

tmrDelayKey is a TTimer with a delay of 1000 ms.
IsSearching is a boolean property.

This is no working code as the user stop writing it searching.
How can this be improved ?

Comment: You might intercept for Char(13) to search on demand. You could reset the timer (disbled/enabled) in OnKeyup and handle searching and disabling the timer within the OnTimer.

Comment: For that search edit I would write a component [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/45Z2d7pE). It takes into account any change, not just when the user types on the keyboard (you should consider cases like pasting a text through the popup menu e.g.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this code should work:

```
var SearchComplete: Boolean;

procedure TForm1.DoSearch(Astring: String);
begin
  SearchComplete:= True;
  txtSearchAgreementCustomer.Text := 'Searched: '+Astring;
end;

procedure TForm1.tmrDelayKeyTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not SearchComplete then
  begin
    DoSearch(txtSearchAgreementCustomer.Text);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.txtSearchAgreementCustomerKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
var C: Char;
begin
  C:= Char(Key);
  if (C in ['a' .. 'z']) or (C in ['A' .. 'Z']) or (C in ['0'..'9']) then
    SearchComplete := False;
end;


procedure TForm1.txtSearchAgreementCustomerExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  tmrDelayKey.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.txtSearchAgreementCustomerEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  tmrDelayKey.Enabled := True;
  SearchComplete := True;
end;
```

Comment: Btw. Roland, have you considered situation when the user will type something and then pastes the text from clipboard through the context menu by mouse ? That will result to a text searched after the user stops writing and timeout elapses, but in the edit box will be text pasted from the clipboard. I would really prefer to use the change event.

Answer (score 5):

The fundamental problem is that your search is synchronous and is blocking the UI. Adding a delay doesn't really help. It just takes even longer for the user to get the feedback.

What you need to do is perform the search asynchronously. For instance put it in another thread. When the search completes, signal the main thread so that it can display the results. If the user types before the search is complete, the search should be restarted with the updated search term.

This approach gives you responsive UI and delivers  the search results as soon as possible.

**Note**: I'm assuming that there is no reason for you to want to avoid searching repeatedly. If it is expensive to search then you absolutely do not want to implement search as you type.

Comment: Yes, you'll get a responsible UI, but you will bother the searched source (think about remote requests) with absolutely every change you type... Users will be happy, but server will suffer. There are just cases where I would implement this kind of delay. Of course, make that search asynchronous is a must...

Comment: @TLama Yes, I had not even contemplated that searching may be expensive and should be rationed. I did not contemplate that because it seems to be at odds with search as you type. I added some text to clarify.

Comment: The implementation of search made it impossible to move it from main thread.

Comment: Impossible seems rather strong.